# Efficiently Using A Function Output

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been attempting to learn C++ over the past few weeks and have a question regarding good practice.

Let's say I have a function that will produce some object. Is it better to define the function to produce an output of type object, or is it better to have the function be passed an object pointer as an argument such that it can modify it directly?

I suppose this answer is dependent on the scenario, but I'm curious if efficiency comes into play. When passing objects into a function as an argument, I know it is more efficient to use const reference such that the function has immediate access to the object with no need of generating a copy.

Does such concern of efficiency come into play when outputting function results?

Comment: In general, pass by value. The language allows copies to be elided and heavy objects to be moved, and compilers can propagate constants very well. By contrast, if you pass a reference or pointer, the compiler has to assume the worst in terms of aliasing and is much more constrained.

Comment: When you say pass by value, are you suggesting to define the function with a specific output? Or are you suggesting that the function input argument should also be passed by value?

Comment: Nice way to use T& function(T& t), so you will pass just references, and not allocate memory inside function for output, and function output still may be used.
If you will pass const reference, you will need to copy object inside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following:

```
MyType someFunc()
{
    MyType result;
    // produce value here
    return result;
}
```

Used like this:

```
MyType var = someFunc();
```

Will do no copy, and no move, but rather [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). 
This means that it can't get more efficient anyway, and it is
also easy to read, **and hard to use wrong**. [Don't help the compiler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKtHxKJRwp4).

Answer (score 0):

You can return created object as a pointer or shared pointer from function. This is useful for immediate checking return value.

```
std::shared_ptr<Object> CreateObject(int type)
{
   if (type == SupportedType)
       return std::make_shared<Object>();
   else
       return std::shared_ptr<Object>();
}
...
if (std::shared_ptr<Object> object = CreateObject(param))
   // do something with object
else
   // process error
```

This is more compact way than passing reference to object's pointer as param and maybe a bit more intuitive.

Comment: I would recommend using `std::shared_ptr` only when ownership really is shared. This seems like a case for `boost::optional`

Answer (score 0):

By passing things by reference you are saving memory resources, this will prevent you from creating copies of things when not needed.

I find it is good practice to pass everything as constant pointers initially and go back and change if needed. This makes sure you are really aware of the structure of your code.

Answer (score 0):

As the best practice, often having easy-to-read code is the most important factor. See what method makes that block of code easier to read and go that way. In most cases [the answer by sp2danny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33471758/1334399) is the clearest.

If for your project the speed has the highest priority then test all the possible methods and see which one is faster. Because most likely your code is more complicated than calling a single function and getting an object back, and probably a few other functions interact with that object too. Hence, you should consider the whole code while trying to improve the speed.